# Duplicate Content To Another Page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to ask about PHP and MySQL. I have 2 page of php, let's called it content.php and duplicate.php. At content php, there's a searching form and a table for form search result.

What I want to ask is: can I make table result at content.php duplicate to duplicate.php (just the table, without the form)? What I'm thinking now is using session, but I don't think that is better way to solve my problem. Or if it is the best way, what content that I must keep at session? query? Or what?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: do you want the data to be non-persistent? so I assume you search it first and go to duplicate.php and the result should be there temporarily?

Comment: just like @Bizarre answer, that's what I'm looking for... Thanks for comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//do query to MySQL
$content = "";
$content .= "<table>";
$content .= "<tr><td>put your data</td></tr>";
$content .= "</table>";

$_SESSION['my_content'] = $content;
```

use the my_content session to echo that content in duplicate.php. hope that helps you....depend on what you want to do. if you just want to make it in one page, use Kolink comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just use one file, and enclose relevant parts in things like `if( isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: No, it's not what I mean, what I mean is to duplicate the table to another page.. That button just works for form right?